# Executing a Function from Another Class in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hello im trying to execute a function from another class in python. I have tried doing this all in the same class and now im trying this in separate classes. The goal here is to have a graph display in a tkinter window underneath the buttons. I wrote a function that produces a graph, I was trying to get it to execute the graph function after the GUI components have been loaded. Later on I am going to have parameters passed to it, hence why it needs to be a function. The error im getting is AttributeError: 'graphPlotter' object has no attribute 'tk. Does anyone know a work around for this or perhaps a smarter way to do it? Please see code below:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TKAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class graphPlotter:

    def graphdis(self):


# ***** Component graph Display *****
        f=Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a=f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

class GUIWindow:
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('1200x650')
    # ****** GUI buttons *********
    radomeButton = Button(root, text="Radome", bd="4")

    wingsButton = Button(root, text="Wings", bd="4")
    engineButton = Button(root, text="Engine", bd="4")
    finsButton = Button(root, text="Fins", bd="4")
    fuelButton = Button(root, text="Fuel", bd="4")

    radomeButton.place(x=25,y=25)

    wingsButton.place(x=175,y=25)
    engineButton.place(x=235,y=25)
    finsButton.place(x=300,y=25)
    fuelButton.place(x=356,y=25)

    graphGrab = graphPlotter()

    graphGrab.graphdis()

    root.mainloop()
```

I am relatively new to python so Im certain im missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: class `GUIWindow` looks horrible. Using classes in your program seems useless. Maybe remove lines with word `class` and you get better program.

Comment: Please post _at least_ the full traceback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas needs correct parent - `root`

Now it works but it doesn't look good because you mix `place` and `pack` layout manager.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TKAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class GraphPlotter:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # remember parent
        self.parent = parent

    def graphdis(self):

        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6])

        # canvas need correct parent - root
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.parent) 
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


class GUIWindow:

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('1200x650')

        # ****** GUI buttons *********
        radomeButton = Button(root, text="Radome", bd="4")

        wingsButton = Button(root, text="Wings", bd="4")
        engineButton = Button(root, text="Engine", bd="4")
        finsButton = Button(root, text="Fins", bd="4")
        fuelButton = Button(root, text="Fuel", bd="4")

        radomeButton.place(x=25, y=25)

        wingsButton.place(x=175, y=25)
        engineButton.place(x=235, y=25)
        finsButton.place(x=300, y=25)
        fuelButton.place(x=356, y=25)

        # use `root` as parent for canvas
        graphGrab = GraphPlotter(root)

        graphGrab.graphdis()

        root.mainloop()

GUIWindow()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I know it doesnt look great now but I just wanted to get it on there I will place it better with place(). I building this into something much bigger.